# Getting a Random Point within a Geometry area

Tags: sql-server, geocoding, sqlgeometry

`STPointOnSurface()` seems to always return the same point. How can I generate a random point located within the interior of geometry in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE with the extents of your surface defined in the WHERE clause, but add a row number for each point returned in your SELECT.  Then query your CTE, but choose the point with a random row number using the row number you assigned in the CTE.

This assumes that you are speaking about a surface that is defined by a point cloud and not by borders/edges.  If your data is defined by borders/edges then you can use a simple distance formula with a random modifier.

Comment: The surfaces are defined by borders/edges. I do not think a distance function will work because the shapes are irregular.